# Possibility of CR without LF

Tags: windows, win32gui

Is it possible to ever read from a Windows Win32 control and get a CR without a LF or vice-versa?

```
CR === Carriage Return 
LF === Line Feed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: Textbox will not re-encode new lines, so if original value (i.e. pasted to control) included particular CR/LF combinations they will stay there.